# Unreachable Browser Exception with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am running some automated test cases using safari webdriver and i face the issue unreachable browser exception most of the time. And few other times it works but 50% of the time selenium cannot launch the safari browser.

```
Aug 18, 2014 5:35:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 5608
Aug 18, 2014 5:35:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Aug 18, 2014 5:35:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Uninstalling extensions
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Uninstalling extensions  
Aug 18, 2014 5:36:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
2014-08-18 17:36:33 ERROR myProject:217 - Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45182     ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '***', ip: '****', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:     'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
```

Should i set some capabilities for the safari webdriver while launching the browser?

Comment: Whats your timeout set to? It looks like your exceeding 45 seconds.  What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Also whats your safari driver initialization code look like?

Comment: @bcar I am using the 2.41 and also i haven't set any capabilities. driver = new SafariDriver(); This is what  i did. Should i  manually set a time out?

Comment: Is your driver a RemoteWebdriver or a WebDriver?

Comment: Are you able to try latest selenium version or are you stuck on 2.41?

Comment: it is a webdriver. I din't use the latest one. I will try the latest one and check it out. @bcar

Comment: @bcar how to set the time outs to launch the browser?